# What's the best way to handle date formatting and translation?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, datetime

I'm currently trying to translate a timestamp field of a content type, but month names are always in English. I want the following format in English and French:

- English : 3 November 2016
- French : 3 novembre 2016

**Code 1 (always in English)**

```
# node--content-type.html.twig
{{ node.field_ends_at.value|date("d F Y") }}
```

**Code 2 (always in English)**

```
# Pass trought field display (Structure > Content type > Manage Display > Format Custom (d F Y)
# node--content-type.html.twig
{{ content.field_ends_at }}
```

What's the best way to handle date formatting and translation?

Comment: The last example works for me. I've got a translated month.

Comment: You need to explain how you have translation set up for your site, as it matters here.  I just added a language to a site, configured translation for a content type, added a translated for the node, and got it to work, both with the default formatter in the default render array and with `{{ content.field_date_time }}` in the template.